# 2sxc Data from another app and zone

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using 2sxc 8.5.4 on DNN Evoq, i have an App which is in Portal 0 and i'm showing the content of this in child apps.

I created a template and created a query to fetch data from the App in Portal 0 by adding its App id and Zone id.

All works fine, when i update the App content in Portal 0, changes are shown instantly in Child portals.

Problem is that the changes only show instantly to the browser i'm currently editing the changes. Example: if i edit the changes in Chrome, changes reflect instantly on Chrome but in Firefox or another PC it takes awhile to show the changes.

I believe its a cache issues, but don't know what else i can do within the visual query to show changes instantly on all browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

The following is the snapshot of the visual query:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's something a bit different, since you're not using a cache-data-source as far as I can tell.

Could it be that you are providing the data as JSON to the browser using the API or similar? because then the browsers have a default behaviour to cache this, unless you are in F12 mode or something.

please try to provide more details if this is wrong.